# Display NSString as HTML text - show string as a link

Tags: iphone, html, nsstring

I have a string wherein there may a phone number, mail address, web address, an email address or it may be some plain text. For example: my phone number is 8009000300.

Firstly, how to display this string as HTML text?

Secondly, if displayed as HTML text, will/can 8009000300 (or web address or mail address or email address) be displayed as a link? I am going for this approach as **NIAttributedLabel** didn't work for me.

**Note**: Phone number (or other special strings) may be there in between the complete string or at the start/end of string.

Comment: you can use UITextView for displaying text. set the dataDetectorTypes property to UIDataDetectorTypeLink.

Comment: My string is Please contact abc at 800.493.0016, option #3 for further assistance. The code is :    UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
                myTextView.frame = rect;
                myTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                myTextView.text = @"Please contact abc at 800.493.0016, option #3 for further assistance.";
                myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
               
                [cell.contentView addSubview:myTextView];
                [myTextView sizeToFit];

Comment: But there is not link being displayed for 800.493.0016

Comment: Awesome. Mudit please post your answer so that it is useful in future and also I can accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: One thing more. What is the text is address  (physical address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UITextView` for displaying text  and  set the `dataDetectorTypes` property to `UIDataDetectorTypeLink`,`UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber` according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreText, or try [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) or [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).

Comment: I also tried that. But it is not all useful. It does not provide actions for links. It can only open url's but can't perform actions like make a call or open google map.

Comment: You can make a call by open url `tel:8009000300`.

Comment: `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino` directly, check the Document: [Map Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html)